Managing external token acquisition from Windows desktop Java application
When writing a Java desktop application to run in Windows, I would like to gain authorization to make requests on certain protected web assets.  The owner of the assets have defined a process whereby a token is generated after the user enters their credentials into a page on the data owner's site. The owner's site then performs a redirect, which includes the token. The token allows protected API calls, and background processing may progress.
For an example of this process, you may go to the Sample API Call, click Authorize as a Beneficiary, complete the login with the sandbox credentials supplied.  In the case of this example, the redirect is back to the development sandbox page, where it shows you the token.
The programming problem I'm trying to solve is how to manage that process with only a Windows desktop application, written in Java.
Using okhttp, I am able to generate the appropriate call to https://sandbox.bluebutton.cms.gov/v2/o/authorize, including appropriate URL parameters, and execute that call:
private static String doFirstGet(OkHttpClient client) throws IOException {
    
    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(BASE_URL + "/v2/o/authorize").newBuilder()
    .addQueryParameter("response_type", "code")
    .addQueryParameter("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
    .addQueryParameter("redirect_uri", URLEncoder.encode(REDIRECT_URL, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()))
    .addQueryParameter("state", STATE);
    
    String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    Response response = call.execute();

    System.out.println("response " + response.code() + " (should be 200)");
    
    String returnString = response.body().string();
    
    System.out.println("response body to string\n" + returnString);
    
    return returnString;

}

I get back a web page, but it does not include a form that I could interact with.  Besides, I don't think it's a legitimate approach for me to be able to sniff the user's interaction with the web site.  In other words, the user needs to be interacting directly with the web site, and my program only can continue when the redirect is done.  I was thinking that maybe I have to open the default browser and let the user interact there, but then I'd need to capture the redirect.  I might set-up a local web server and redirect back to https:\\localhost\...?  But that doesn't seem right.
This seems like a common problem that desktop application developers would run into, but I haven't found example code or guidance on how to proceed.
What is the appropriate way to structure the application such that the user is able to be directed from the Windows application, to the data owner web site, and back to the Windows application such that the application may proceed with the generated access_token?
